By using detox framework and jest, how to automate TimePicker in react native app
By using setDatePickerDate action method, I am able to automate a date picker.
But there is no action method provided by detox for setting time time picker.
By using detox and jest, How to set the time in TimePicker ?
I need a solution for automating TimePicker in react native app using detox and jest.
